# Convert NGINX Location Directive To Apache

Tags: apache2, nginx

I've tried doing this myself and looking at the Apache Mod docs, but I am running into trouble.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<Location /chat>
    SetHandler chat

    RewriteRule      ^/chat(/.+)$ $1
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000
    RequestHeader    set Host $host
    RequestHeader    set Cookie $http_cookie
</Location>
```

Can someone familiar with NGINX and Apache convert the following please?

```
location /chat {
        rewrite            /chat(/.+)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_buffering    off;
        proxy_send_timeout 310;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try to post you're question to http://serverfault.com/ , you can use you're stackoverflow username to login and you'll have more chances for the best answer there

Comment: thanks and yeah I have just done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually using NGINX in production.  So this question is moot. :)